# How can I find the line number in a delimited file which has < 20 characters?

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file, which has one line which is less than 20 characters length.

I wanted to find the line number and remove that line alone from that file.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -vn '.\{20,\}' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

**sed** approach:

```
sed -i '/^.\{1,19\}$/d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'length >= 20' file
```

or, for the complete "remove those lines from the file" scenario:

```
awk 'length >= 20' file >tmpfile && mv tmpfile file
```